# Django-taggit: how to retrieve all tags filtered by a certain type of posts

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm building a blog, and I have two status for a post, Published and a Draft.
I wanto to display all tags of all published posts using Django-taggit.

here's how a get all tags for all kind of posts, Published and Draft in my view:

```
object_list = Post.published.all()
tags = Tag.objects.filter()
```

And I want to get only tags for published posts

I got stuck, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
inner_qs = Post.published.all().values('tags')
tags = Tag.objects.filter(id__in=inner_qs)
```

You should replace the `tags` value for your actual field name for the tag, and the same thing with the `id` field in the tag model in the `id__in` filter.

Hope it helps.